# Where can I find sample data required for Engine Condition Monitoring?

Tags: engine, engine-failure, flight-data-monitoring

I'm trying to find some sample data required for Engine Condition 
Trend Monitoring to analyse and predict when an engine might fail.

I went through a lot of research papers and (kind of) understood the parameters needed for Engine Condition Trend Monitoring. From what I've understood, I need Exhaust Gas Temperature, Fuel Flow, Low Pressure Fan Speed, High Pressure Rotor Speed, Engine Pressure Ratio and EGT Margin data.

I'm doing this as a part of my college project and I need some sample data to start working. 
Also, please correct me if I'm wrong because I'm very new to all this.

Comment: Welcome. *Where can I find x* is [off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site as it is considered shopping / resource finding. Click on the link for more information.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, my bad. Should I delete the question?

Comment: No, don’t delete the question (it is still a good question).  A small change in phasing such as “what data is required for engine conditioning monitoring” fixes any issue moderators might have, so no need to make a drastic move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list of parameters is on the right track, and is the minimum set. If you can add a few more temperatures and pressures at other “stations” within the engine, the diagnostic accuracy improves.

No one on the internet will send you real data. OEMs and operators don’t give out data, because it contains proprietary information. That’s why 90% of the papers you have read probably use simulated data. Also, with simulated data, you actually know what the fault was. With a real engine, you don’t because when you pull an engine apart, there is no simple dimension you can measure to tell you what the change in efficiency of the fan actually is, for example. But, the trick with simulated data is to add a realistic amount of noise.

To generate simulated data you need a gas turbine performance program, like [GasTurb](http://www.gasturb.de) or [GSP.](https://www.gspteam.com) The latter of these is free for personal use. Maybe if you google “gas turbine performance simulation software” you will be lucky and find something free that does enough for your research.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'm a computer science student and so my knowledge about all this is extremely limited. I only started reading about aircraft engine today.

I'll search for free softwares and also see if I can find any mutual friend who works in the aviation industry. Maybe they will have access to the software. Your reply truly helped a lot. Thank you!

Comment: NASA has an extremely basic jet engine simulator available for free https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/ngnsim.html  It's not anywhere near what a major OEM would use, but it's free and might get you started.

Comment: That's good to know! Thanks Daniel, I'll check it out.